# Blank brackets return when webscraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using Chrome driver to web **scrape** some information on vehicles. When trying to get the star rating, it is returning empty brackets "[]" as the result. Can someone point me in the correct direction?  Here is the code that I'm running:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.edmunds.com/subaru/forester/2020/consumer-reviews/?pagenum=1/")

for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-item text-gray-darker']"):
    rating = review.find_elements_by_xpath("div[@class='truncated-text size-16']/div/div/div/dl[1]/dd/span[@aria-label]/text()")
    print(rating)
    
driver.close()
```

And get this in return:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to scrape from the above page?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to scrape. But I'm guessing you want the star ratings. Your code is targeting the wrong element. For the ratings, you can try this in the for loop:

```
rating = review.find_element_by_css_selector("span.rating-stars").get_attribute("aria-label")
```